# How to count the number of distinct values for each specific

Tags: sql

I have a database containing two separate fields A and B.  I want to find out if for any given value of A there are multiple rows with different values of B.

I have tried using group by and distinct but I am doing something wrong, because I keep getting results which, when I query the specific value of A, all the values of B are the same.  I have tried variants on the following including:

```
SELECT COUNT(B) FROM ex1 GROUP BY A HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B) FROM ex1 GROUP BY A HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B) > 1;
```

Strangely, this last one wound up giving me results where for a given value of B there were multiple values of A, which is backwards from what I wanted.  I tried reversing A and B in the last query but that wound up giving me cases where A only had a single value of B.

How can I get records for only where there is a specific value of A in multiple records, each of which has a different value for B?

Comment: Your second query looks correct, but you want to select `A`.

Comment: how  about select a,b ,count(*) as cnt from FILE group by a having cnt >1

Comment: @GordonLinoff The second query won't work if there's a single row for `A`, as it will have a unique value for `B` but be excluded because the count is not greater than 1

Comment: @Tony OP only wants A where there are **multiple** B: *I want to find out if for any given value of A there are **multiple** rows with different values of B*

Comment: @Bohemian - Ah yes! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

"records for only where there is a specific value of A in multiple records, each of which has a different value for B?"

```
SELECT DISTINCT ex1a.A
FROM ex1 ex1a
WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(ex1b.B) FROM ex1 ex1b WHERE ex1a.A=ex1b.A) 
= (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ex1b.B) FROM ex1 ex1b WHERE ex1a.A=ex1b.A) 
AND
(SELECT COUNT(ex1c.B) FROM ex1 ex1c WHERE ex1a.A = ex1c.A) > 1
```

And, you can remove the last SELECT if you want to include the case where there is just 1 (distinct) record for A and B.

Comment: strange, i'm getting results where there is exactly one row, so there can't be more than one value of B

Comment: did you really mean to put `WHERE ex1c.A=ex1c.A`? Ah, I see you fixed that while I was typing :)

Comment: Ooops, I had a typo.  Please try again now.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
create table want as
select a,b,count(*)as cnt from(
select a,b,count(*) as num from have
group by a, b)
group by a having cnt > 1;
```

Comment: You have some syntax errors in your query: you are selecting `a,b,count(*)` in the first `select` but only grouping by `a`, and the derived table doesn't have an alias.